# phpMyAdmin doesn't prompt for username or password

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin was working fine until it wasn't.  Currently the index.php page will come up as usual, displaying the logo and 'Welcome' message but the language, username and password prompts are not displayed.

MySQL is still working without any known problems.

Two recent issues: drive filled up due to a log file filling up and I installed an application that required Jetty and Java utilities.

I've reviewed settings in the config.inc.php file and everything seems to be in order.

Can anyone suggest a reason for this happening.  I'm getting a little tired of typing MySQL commands.